# Merge two files (use line number instead of common field)

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

Input file1:

```
1
5
6
```

Input file2:

```
4.5
6.7
9.9
```

Output:

```
1  4.5
5  6.7
6  9.9
```

I tried `join` but it doesn't work here as there's no common field. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `paste` command rather than `join`, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> cat file1
1
5
6

pax> cat file2
4.5
6.7
9.9

pax> paste file1 file2
1   4.5
5   6.7
6   9.9
```

Consult your friendly neighbourhood `man` page (or `info` page) for more details, such as using `-d` to select delimiters other than <kbd>TAB</kbd>, or `-s` to process the files sequentially rather than in parallel.

```
pax> paste -d= file1 file2
1=4.5
5=6.7
6=9.9

pax> paste -d, -s file1 file2
1,5,6
4.5,6.7,9.9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' file2 file1
```

tested below:

```
> cat file2
a 
b
c
> cat file1
1 
100
90
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' file2 file1
a 1 
b 100
c 90
```